# Laravel 5.8 hasOneThrough relationship problems

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

Can someone PLEASE correct this! I have been banging my head on it on and off for two days! I have never managed to successfully make a hasOneThrough relationship work, but I decided to try again. Right now the error I am getting is "Call to undefined method App\Models\OppModels\opp_main::hasOneThrough()". I believe my issue is with the local keys vs foriegn keys, but if I truly knew the issues, then i could fix it. I do realize I could hard code the org_id into my opp_main table, but I really want to make this work due to future considerations. My table design is:

```
---------
opp_main
---------
id
---------

---------
opp_org
---------
id
opp_id
org_id
---------

---------
org_main
---------
id
---------
```

My relationship looks this (the comments were taken from the documentation to try to organize it in my mind):

```
public function org()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            'App\Models\OrgModels\org_main', // Final model
            'App\Models\OppModels\opp_org',  // Intermediate model
            'opp_id',                        // Foreign key on intermediate model
            'id',                            // Foreign key on the final model
            'id',                            // local key
            'org_id'                         // local key of the intermediate model
        );
    }
```

And this is how I am calling it (I have tried both $item->org; and $item->org(); ):

```
public function getAllOpportunities() 
    {
        $opps = opp_main::orderBy('status', 'asc')->get();
        $opps->map(function ($item) {
            $item['org'] = $item->org;
            return $item;
        });

        return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'data' => $opps ]); 
    }
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation this is how it is supposed to be arranged. Note difference from your solution

- Org_main has an FK to opp_org which is needed in hasOneThrough() to
  link the required model to the intermediate model

---

### org_main

id

### opp_org_id

---

opp_org
id
opp_id

### org_id

---

opp_main

### id

```
return $this->hasOneThrough(
    'org_main', // final model
    'opp_org', // intermediate or linking model
    'opp_id', //fk on opp_org linking to opp_main
    'opp_org_id', // fk on org_main linking ot opp_org table,
    'id', //local key on opp_main
    'id', //local key on opp_org / intermediate model
);
```

Comment: I dont understand. If I did that, I wouldnt need a hasOneThrough, I could do a simple hasOne. But it would also mean that each org_main (organization) could only have one opp_main (opportunity). I need opp_main to link through opo_org to org_main, with neither opp_main nor org_main hardcoded to each other

Comment: What you are trying to do looks to me like a many-to-many where opp_org is the pivot table? So you can have many orgs with many ops and neither would have their relationship keys encoded in themselves. The links would only be in the opp_org table [Many-To-Many Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)